# decision making and recursive functions

Tags: c++

i want to make a calculator without the GUI, but i have some problem like this

```
cout<<"calculator : ";cin>>userAnswer;
if(userAnswer=='yes'){
      //procces
} else if(userAnswer=='no'){
      //exit
} else{
      //here is the problem
}
```

when the user enters an input that aside from yes or no I want the program to ask the user again whether the user wants to use the calculator again.
but I don't know how. I have used a recursive function, but the number of times a user enters a wrong input, so the program will ask "does the user want to use a calculator?"

Comment: Simple `while` loop should do the job for you. Why Recursion?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this -

```
while (true) {
    cout<<"calculator : ";
    while(true) {
         cin>>userAnswer;
         if(userAnswer=='yes'){
              //procces
         } else if(userAnswer=='no'){
              //exit
         } else {
              break;
         }
    }
    cout<<"Do you want to use a calculator? ";
    string feedback;
    cin >> feedback;
    if ( feedback == "yes") {
        continue;
    } else {
       break;
    }
}
```

Comment: i have found the answer of my problem using while in while

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this I guess,

```
string userAnswer;
cout<<"calculator : ";
cin>>userAnswer;
while(true)
{
    while(true)
    {
        cout<<"\ndoes the user want to use the calculator : ";
        cin>>userAnswer;
        if(userAnswer=="yes" || userAnswer=="no")
                break;
        else
            cout<<"only yes or no input is valid\n";
    }
    if(choice=="no")
        {
            cout<<"\nExiting from the calculator\n";
            break;
        }

        cout<<"Enter your choice: \n";
        cout<<"1-Addition\n";
        cout<<"2-Subtraction\n";

        // your stuff below
}
```